# dotnet: ListChangedType.ItemDeleted is useless?

Tags: .net, data-binding

The ListChanged event for an IBindingList fires a type ListChangedType.ItemDeleted when items are deleted, perhaps by a user deleting a row in a datagrid control bound to the list. The problem is that the NewIndex into the list is invalid in this event, it's been deleted, and the item that was deleted is not available. There should be an ItemDeleting event, but I doubt they will ever fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah it's pretty annoying, but there is an easy workaround. I create a `BindingListBase<T>` class that I use for all of my lists instead of using a normal `BindingList<T>`. Because my class inherits from the `BindingList<T>`, I have access to all of it's protected members, including the `RemovedItem` method.

This enables me to pick up when an item is removed. You could do what I do and have a mRemovedItems list that I always add items to, or raise your own 'ItemRemoved' event.

See my code example below:

```
Public MustInherit Class BindingListBase(Of T)
    Inherits BindingList(Of T)

    Protected mRemovedItems As New List(Of T)

    Protected Overrides Sub ClearItems()
        MyBase.ClearItems()
        mRemovedItems.Clear()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RemoveItem(ByVal index As Integer)
        Dim item As T = MyBase.Item(index)

        MyBase.RemoveItem(index)

        mRemovedItems.Add(item)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property RemovedItems as List(Of T)
        Get
            Return mRemovedItems
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not really intended for that purpose. `NewIndex` is the index where the item was when it was deleted, and it's useful for bound controls to be able to locate their associated display item in their own lists and remove that.

What is the use case you want to enable with an `ItemDeleting`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of a BindingList class that implements an ItemRemoved event, rather than keeping a secondary list of deleted items

```
public class ItemRemovedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Object Item { get; set; }

    public ItemRemovedEventArgs(Object item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }
}

public delegate void ItemRmoveEventHandler(Object sender, ItemRemovedEventArgs e);

public class BindingListRedux<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    public BindingListRedux() : base() { }

    public BindingListRedux(IList<T> list) : base(list) { }

    public event ItemRmoveEventHandler ItemRemoved;

    protected void OnItemRemoved(ItemRemovedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemRemoved != null)
        {
            ItemRemoved(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        Object item = base[index];
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        this.OnItemRemoved(new ItemRemovedEventArgs(item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to what Adam Valpied did, i.e. implemented my own class with a ListChanging event-handler.  That lets me work with the item that's about to be removed from the list before it actually does.

In response to Sunlight's question regarding the use case...among other things, I use it to remove event-handlers that were put on the contained item when it was put into the list.  My data-elements contain an error-severity level, determined during validation, and the GUI elements they're bound to display that error-severity as a background color.  When the data-element's error-severity level changes, the GUI element must be updated.  So I have to put a HighestSeverityChanged event-handler on the data-element when it's displayed (whether by itself or as part of a list that's being displayed), and I need to remove that event-handler when the GUI element is unbound from the data-element.